# Compress Large size of satellite image by Open Source GIS software

Tags: qgis, geoserver, open-source-gis, image, satellite

I have a new challenge to compress large size of satellite image from 59GB to 10GB as maximum size by Open Source GIS software to publish it to GeoServer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt follow Paul Ramsey's [GeoTiff compression for dummies](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html) strategy.

```
gdal_translate \
  -co COMPRESS=JPEG \
  -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR \
  -co TILED=YES \
  5255C.tif 5255C_JPEG_YCBCR.tif
```

and if you need overviews too then add

```
gdaladdo \
  --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG \
  --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR \
  --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL \
  -r average \
  5255C_JPEG_YCBCR.tif \
  2 4 8 16
```

Comment: thank you very much @Ian Turton, i did not use gdal command before, any guideline about that?

Comment: just copy and paste the above, changing the filenames as required